# How is the poisson data generated inside of the special.pdtr function?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm interested in understanding how the special.pdtr function is generated as I'd like to see the computational method. I'm working on a project to see if I could calculate it in a similar way to simulate another slightly more complex probability distribution.

I've looked in the documentation and all it does is reference the general form of the probability distribution but doesn't say how the code comes up with the output.

Comment: It's a `ufunc`, so it's compiled.  So you'd have to search the `scipy` `github` repository to fined the underlying code (probably `c`, maybe `cython`).

Comment: Can you reproduce the values for the documentated case?  With what code, and/or what differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `scipy.special` function, so to find it, you need to look at the file [scipy/special/functions.json](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/special/functions.json#L1210).

```
    "pdtr": {
        "cephes.h": {
            "pdtr": "dd->d"
        }
    },
```

This tells us that `pdtr` is implemented using a function also called `pdtr`. (This isn't always the case - sometimes the implementation has a different name.) It also tells us that the code came from the [Cephes library](https://www.netlib.org/cephes/).

Next, [search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ascipy%2Fscipy%20pdtr&type=code) the SciPy repo for "pdtr." Look for C, Cython, or Fortran, as that's usually how these are implemented.

This finds an implementation inside [scipy/special/cephes/pdtr.c](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/special/cephes/pdtr.c#L146).

```
double pdtr(double k, double m)
{
    double v;

    if (k < 0 || m < 0) {
        sf_error("pdtr", SF_ERROR_DOMAIN, NULL);
        return (NAN);
    }
    if (m == 0.0) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    v = floor(k) + 1;
    return (igamc(v, m));
}
```

This tells us that when it is computing the poisson CDF, it is actually using the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) to do so.

You may also find it useful to read how the [igamc](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/special/cephes/igam.c#L169) function is implemented. To summarize, it chooses between one of three different approximations, depending on where in the gamma function it is. It also uses some identities of the incomplete gamma function to reduce more complex cases to simpler cases which can be evaluated more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

At least for integer `k`, this reproduces the values

```
def foo(k,m):
    # \exp(-m) \sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor{k}\rfloor} \frac{m^j}{j!}
    res = [m**j/special.factorial(j) for j in range(0,k+1)]
    res = np.sum(res)
    res = np.exp(-m) * res
    return res
```

It is slower because it iterates on `k`.